# Why is there extra space to the left of my site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, space

There seems to be a problem with the website I'm coding. I want the slideshow to extend to the full width of the screen which does. However, I see an extra space on the left side and right side of the screen. Any ideas on how to fix this while keeping the slideshow the way it is?

This is the link of the site: http://cgarcia2595.bugs3.com/redo%20twice%20website/

Comment: I don't see extra space to the left or to the right on chrome. May be its some css issue. Try adding padding:0, margin: 0 to the html, body elements in css.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is designed for the screen with width 1440px. You need to use `width: 100%` to take all the screen.
Also, no need to specify width on the `html` element.
Also, you may need to reset the default padding of the `body` element.

Comment: set width: 100%; and set max-width: 1440px;

Answer (score 0):

elements have default `margin` / `padding`.

you can reset them to zero by adding this to your **CSS**

```
*
{
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `html, body` width does not need to be set. Unsetting the `width` of that however does not fully fix your issue because your `div#main`'s `position` is set to `absolute`. That will take it out of the normal flow of the page (which will keep it on the left side of the page). You will need to remove the `position: absolute;` CSS from your `div#main` element to fully correct the issue.

If you're wondering about the large amount of space to the left of your menu, that is for several various reasons. Your menu itself may need to be centered if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: The menu is fine, I'm going to add a logo on the side of the menu. I was wondering of the sides of the main div. I'm sure there is a way to make the slideshow extend fully so it could touch both side of the margins of the browser.